# The virtual machine os does not support mouse pointer integration

Tags: virtual-machine, mouse, virtualization

I was trying to set up a VM via Oracle Virtual Box in my MacBook.

> **Host OS**: Mac
>
> **Application**: Oracle Virtual
>
> **VM OS**: CentOS 7

While I'm trying to start the OS installation I found that mouse capturing of the VM is not working correctly.

> Observation: Once the mouse pointer captured in the VM, It's not
>   visible as expected

And also I got a pop-up message related to this;

> Pop-up message:  **The virtual machine reports that the guest os does
>   not support mouse pointer integration in the current video mode**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Shut-Down the VM
2. Select a particular VM and go to settings

   [image: VM-Settings]
3. Go to **System** section

   [image: System-section]
4. In the **Motherboard** tab, change the Pointing Device as below;
   From: **PS/2 mouse**
   To: **USB Tablet** OR **USB Multi-touch Tablet**

   [image: Change-poiting-device]
5. Save settings and Start the VM

Comment: Also some times (in mac) you have to add the device in 'Machines > Settings > Ports > USB > USB DEVICE FILTERS  (click +  on RHS to see the list ) and select the device to be added.  On submit the vm might logout.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. In my case the issue started occurring when I switched from the USB2 to the USB3 controller in the settings of the VM (Ubuntu 23.10 host, Windows 7 guest).

Comment: Perfect.  This issue kept coming up during video calls on a Windows host.  Slack and Teams would interact with the mouse just enough to mess it up.  Switching to USB Multi-Touch Tablet did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I had this message when I tried copying to/from Terminal to outside text and vice versa.

I could enable it from the VBox interface once the Guest OS has started!

```
Devices --> Shared Clipboard --> to Bidirectional
```

The menus are File | Machine | View | Input | **Devices** | Help